# ImageView seem to be recycled as soon they leave the screen in a RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I just started using a RecyclerView to display some rows containing an ImageView and a TextView.
Everything is properly displayed when I open the screen. If I scroll fast to the bottom of the list then back up quickly there's no issue.
However, as soon as I scroll down slowly to display the next row and the 1st one isn't displayed anymore scrolling back up will show a black square instead of my bitmap.

I thought onBindViewHolder() would be called again when scrolling up but this only happens after scrolling for 3 rows. 
So it looks like the RecyclerView is prefetching some rows

I tried calling setItemPrefetchEnabled(false); on the layoutManager or setInitialPrefetchItemCount(0);
but it doesn't change anything

Any idea what's going on and how to fix this?

I'm doing a poke so the code is minimal here

// Fragment

```
final RecyclerView view = this.fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
view.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
//layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(false);
//layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(0);
view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

// ViewHolder

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView name;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
}
```

// Adapter

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.id.my_layout, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = buildViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);        
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final MyData myData = this.data.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(myData.getName());
    viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(myData.getThumbnailPath()));
}

private MyViewHolder buildViewHolder(View view) {
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    viewHolder.name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    viewHolder.thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: What does `buildViewHolder(View view)` do?

Comment: I added the missing code, but I don't think this would help understand what's causing this

Comment: Where are the bitmaps coming from? Saved locally pre build, or maybe you download it from server? maybe the problem is with `getBitmap`, because i don't see any problem in `onBindViewHolder` and `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: In this poc they are just local files. This issue isn't related to the bitmap. They are properly loaded and if I scroll quite fast back and forth they are all properly displayed. But in that case the RecyclerView prefetch isn't used. The issue seems to be related with the prefetch

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly, and I also can't comment.
But if your issue is that views are recycled try:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false).
```

inside `onBindViewHolder()` 
this  tells "hey recyclerview, stop recycling the views so much"

Comment: ViewHolder should be recycled, that's not the issue. The problem is that they are not recycled when they leave the screen (unless 3 or more rows have left the screen), but yet their imageview isn't displayed properly after that

Comment: are you sure the image data is loaded properly when view is being created ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like calling

```
this.view.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
```

on my RecyclerView fixes the issue, but I don't understand why this is necessary.
I still would want to understand what's happening here